# How can I divide indices in massive

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I have an sort algorithm

```
def partition(competitors, left, right):
    pivot = competitors[left]
    i = left + 1
    j = right - 1
    while True:
        if (i <= j and competitors[j] > pivot):
            j -= 1
        elif (i <= j and competitors[i] < pivot):
            i += 1
        elif (competitors[j] > pivot) or (competitors[i] < pivot):
            continue
        if i <= j:
            competitors[i], competitors[j] = competitors[j], competitors[i]
        else:
            competitors[left], competitors[j] = competitors[j], competitors[left]
            return j


def quick_sort(competitors, left, right):
    if ((right - left) > 1):
        p = partition(competitors, left, right)
        quick_sort(competitors, left, p)
        quick_sort(competitors, p + 1, right)


def transformation(competitors):
    competitors[1] = - int(competitors[1])
    competitors[2] = int(competitors[2])

    return [competitors[1], competitors[2], competitors[0]]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    number = int(input())
    competitors = [transformation(input().split()) for _ in range(number)]
    quick_sort(competitors, left=0, right=len(competitors))
    print(*(list(zip(*competitors))[2]), sep="\n")
```

Here

```
pivot = competitors[left]
```

Reviewer said that i can get a pivot by divide first and last index in array.
I was try many options and one of that is

```
pivot = competitors[left // right]
```

But output is wrong

Here description of task

**
Let's get two pointers left and right, which appear on the left and right ends of the segment, respectively. Then we will move the left pointer to the right until it triggers an alarm on the element smaller than the pivot. Similarly, we move the right pointer to the left while it is on the element that exceeds the reference one.As a result, it turns out that to the left of left all elements exactly belong to the first group, and to the right of right - to the second. Elements with pointers are out of order. Let's swap them (most programming languages ​​use the swap() function) and advance pointers to the next elements. We will repeat this action until left and right collide.
**

```
Input:
    5
    alla 4 100
    gena 6 1000
    gosha 2 90
    rita 2 90
    timofey 4 80

Output:
    gena
    timofey
    alla
    gosha
    rita
```

```
And my output is: gena
                  timofey
                  alla
                 <rita>
                 <gosha>
```

Please help me to figure out how solve this algorithm

Comment: I have no idea what *"in massive"* means in this context. Can you explain?

Comment: sorry for my english, its array

Comment: You can take `pivot = competitors[(left + right) // 2]`, but you'll have to change some other code for that to work.

Comment: It feels like `rita` compares less than `gosha`. What is your input encoding?

Comment: My input is the same as in task

Answer (score 0):

So this is a new algorithm, I was update it with pivot = competitors[(left + right) // 2] string

```
def partition(competitors, left, right):
    if right <= left:
        return
    pivot = (left + right) // 2
    part = competitors[pivot]
    begin = left
    end = right
    while begin <= end:
        while part > competitors[begin]:
            begin += 1
        while part < competitors[end]:
            end -= 1
        if begin <= end:
            competitors[begin], competitors[end] = competitors[
                end], competitors[begin]
            begin += 1
            end -= 1
    partition(competitors, left, end)
    partition(competitors, begin, right)


def quick_sort(competitors):
    partition(competitors, 0, len(competitors) - 1)
    return [line[2] for line in competitors]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    competitors = [None] * n
    for x in range(n):
        login, Pi, Fi = input().split()
        competitors[x] = (-int(Pi), int(Fi), login)
    result = quick_sort(competitors)
    print(*result, sep="\n")
```